# Large Prob > F in regression

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

On performing regression in stata, the Prob > F value I obtained is 0.1921. I understand that regression coefficients are not significant at 0.01,0.05 or 0.1% levels. Does this mean that my model is not useful?

Also, the corresponding Prob > t for the three coefficients and intercept are respectively 0.09, 0.93, 0.3 and 0.000.
Doesn't this mean that the first coefficient is significant at 0.1% level? What about the intercept term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F-test for a regression model tests whether the slopes (not the intercept) are jointly different from 0. The null hypothesis is false when any of the slopes are different from 0. A large p-value for the F-test means your data are not inconsistent with the null hypothesis, and there is no evidence that any of your predictors have a linear relationship with or explain variance in your outcome. "Redundant" is not the word I'd use to describe your model; it's just not very useful or informative.

Your second question seems to amount to how the p-value on the F-statistic could ever be higher than the highest p-value for the t-tests on the slopes. That's an interesting question that I hope someone else could weigh in on. My intuitions are that type I error rate on the slope t-tests is actually higher than nominal because of the multiple comparisons. That is, with many slopes, there's a good a chance one of them will be significant even if they were all 0 in the population. On the other hand, the F-test is a single joint test that doesn't suffer from familywise inflation of the type I error rate.

Typically, if the F-test is nonsignificant, you should not interpret the t-tests of the slopes. You have already failed to find evidence that any of the slopes are different from 0.

Comment: Do I have to change the predictor variables? What about the 0.1% significance of the first coefficient?

Comment: Edited my answer to address that.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to discard the model and include other variables?

Comment: It depends on what your hypothesis was. If your hypothesis was that at least one of these variables predicted your outcome, then you cannot make any conclusions and you need to collect more data to determine if the coefficients are actually 0 or just too small to estimate with sufficient precision with the size of your present sample.

Comment: Can i choose a level higher than 0.1?

Comment: If your goal was to generate a predictive model, there are a varety of approaches you could take. You could run a more complex model liek a generalized additive model or a more flexible semi-parametric model, or you could employ a machine elarning method like random forests to see if any prediction can be squeezed out of your variables. Otherwise, you can throw in more variables. I wouldn't discard these variables, though; suppression may be acting on yoru model, which means including certain other variables could reveal a real effect of the variables already in your model.

Answer (score 1):

In the output for a regression model with $m$ explanatory variables, the value `Prob > F-value` is the p-value for the goodness-of-fit test, which tests the hypothesis that none of those variables have a relationship with the response variable.  This test uses the hypotheses:

$$H_0: \beta_1 = \cdots = \beta_m = 0 \quad \quad \quad H_A: H_0 \text{ not true}.$$

Your p-value of `0.1921` means that there is no statistically significant evidence to reject the null hypothesis.  Thus, there is no evidence of a relationship (of the kind posited in your model) between the set of explanatory variables and your response variable.